# (Symbol, Any)* と (Symbol, Any)* のマージ

Tags: scala, playframework

play framework（2.4）のScalaテンプレートとして、
カスタムinputヘルパを作成したいと考えています。

カスタムinputヘルパでは、固定のattribute（styleやclass）を付けたいのですが、
カスタムinputヘルパを呼び出す側でもattributeを付けたい場合があります。

そこで、カスタムinputヘルパに渡される(Symbol, Any)* と
カスタムinputヘルパ内で設定したい (Symbol, Any)* をマージできれば良いのではないかと考えました。

ふたつの同じSymbolがあればvalueを文字列として結合するイメージです。

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: helper.FieldConstructor)

@{ ここでargsと 'style -> "aaa", 'class -> "bbb" をマージするイメージ }@

@helper.input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <input type="text" id="@id" name="@id" value="@value" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) />
}
```

どのような方法で実現できるでしょうか。
（template functionとして切り出したいと考えています）.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 解決方法

別途、マージ処理用のScalaソースコードを用意する。（ViewUtility.scala）

```
package hoge.piyo.scala

object ViewUtility {
    def merge(xs: Seq[(Symbol, Any)], ys: Seq[(Symbol, Any)]): Seq[(Symbol, Any)] = {
      (xs ++ ys).groupBy(_._1)
        .mapValues {
          case (_, x) +: Nil         => x
          case (_, x) +: (_, y) +: _ => s"$x$y"
        }
        .toSeq
    }
}
```

テンプレート側で呼び出す。

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol, String)*)(implicit handler: helper.FieldConstructor)

@import hoge.piyo.scala._

@defining(ViewUtility.merge(args, Seq('readonly -> "true", 'tabindex -> "-1", 'style -> "border: none;background-color: transparent;"))) { list =>
  @helper.input(field, list:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    <input type="text" id="@id" name="@id" value="@value" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) />
  }
}
```

htmlArgsにはマージ後（同一Symbolがあったら文字列連結される）の値がセットされる。

※解決にはScala.jpの有志の方の力を全面的にお借りしました